# Проблема с совместимостью PHPExcel и bitrix на одном сервере

Tags: cms, битрикс, phpexcel

В настройках phpexcel

```
if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2) {
    throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Multibyte function overloading in PHP must be disabled for string functions (2).');
}
```

В битриксе другая настройка должна быть, подскажите выход

Нашел вариант писать для каждого виртуального хоста

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value default_charset utf8
    php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 2
    php_value mbstring.internal_encoding utf8
    php_admin_value realpath_cache_size "4096k"
</IfModule>
```

Но у меня openserver  там автоматом формируются вирртуальные хосты, да и совместить нужно на одном сервере.

Comment: У меня была такая проблема. Я просто закомментил вывод данной ошибки в настройках PHPExcel и ничего плохого не случилось.

Comment: @ka3a Я изменил настройки сервера и битрикс не упал =)

Comment: Ну всё таки если вдруг умрёт битрикс, будет куда критичнее, если помрёт PHPExcel :)) Поэтому я выбираю меньшее из двух зол.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать такую конструкцию:

```
shell_exec('php -d extension=zip.so -d extension=xmlwriter.so -n file.php');
```

Предварительно можно сохранить нужные данные во временном файле. В файле `file.php` необходимо подключить PHPExcel без подключения Битрикса.